# Linebreak inside 'align'

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, align

I tried to linebreak inside math mode which did not work. So searching for that led me to try using 'align' instead. So I'm trying to break a line inside align with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
R = \left\{(S_1,S_1), (S_1,S_4), (S_4,S_4), (S_4,S_1), (S_2,S_2), (S_2,S_3),    (S_3,S_3), (S_3,S_2), (S_0,S_0), \\
(S_0, S_5), (S_5,S_5) , (S_5,S_0)\right\}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I get the error message : `Extra }, or forgotten \right. \end{align}` which I don't understand since I do have an opening and closing curly bracket?

Anyhow, the above does break the line in some way but it looks really ugly, and aligned to the right for some reason. Could someone show me how I could align the set I'm trying to write out, nicely on two lines?

Comment: The problem is the `\left\{` which does not see any closure on the same line. Use a `\right.` at the line end. As this formula wont need any auto-expansion of the brackets, you could use `\{` as well.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi But it should not be closed before the last element has been included, it should only break the line and continue.

Comment: The `\right.` just closes the `\left`, `\right` pair. But it prints nothing. There are several post around here, which explain that behaviour.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I still get the same error. Could you write it out in the context of my example please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to fix that, you will have to give the `\left\{` its counterpart which would be `\right.` on the same line. The second line would need a `\left. ... \right\}` .

As you do not need auto-sized brackets here, I would leave it all away.

Here is your example and my version:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    R = \left\{(S_1,S_1), (S_1,S_4), (S_4,S_4), (S_4,S_1), (S_2,S_2), (S_2,S_3), (S_3,S_3), (S_3,S_2), (S_0,S_0),\right. \\
    \left.(S_0, S_5), (S_5,S_5) , (S_5,S_0)\right\}
    \end{align}
    \begin{equation}    
    \begin{split}
        R = \{(S_1,S_1), (S_1,S_4), (S_4,S_4), (S_4,S_1), (S_2,S_2), (S_2,S_3), (S_3,S_3),\\ (S_3,S_2), (S_0,S_0), (S_0, S_5), (S_5,S_5) , (S_5,S_0)\}
    \end{split} 
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And here is a screen-shot of the second version (as the first version exceeds all possible limits...)

[image]

Comment: Oh. I didn't start the \left again. Thank you. I find the equation way of doing it much more intuitive though.

Answer (score 3):

You also can use the following code, heavily inspired by Sebastien Gouezel's code for `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` (pp. 28-29 of `mathtools` documentation), that allows for line breaks in paired delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
\bgroup
\catcode`\&=9
\let\\\relax%
\scantokens{#1}%
\egroup
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set\{\}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\set{star}{
\mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
#2
\mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} R = &\! \begin{aligned}[t]\set[\Big]{&(S_1,S_1), (S_1,S_4), (S_4,S_4), (S_4,S_1), (S_2,S_2), (S_2,S_3), (S_3,S_3), (S_3,S_2), \\
 & (S_0,S_0), (S_0, S_5), (S_5,S_5) , (S_5,S_0)}
 \end{aligned}\\
    R = &\! \begin{aligned}[t]\set{ & (S_1,S_1), (S_1,S_4), (S_4,S_4), (S_4,S_1), (S_2,S_2), (S_2,S_3), (S_3,S_3), (S_3,S_2),\\
     & (S_0,S_0) (S_0, S_5), (S_5,S_5) , (S_5,S_0)}
 \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this code works only with the optional arguments (or no optional argument at all), but *not* with the star version.

[image]

Comment: But the star version appears to work here. Indeed, the declared point of `\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper` is to support the star version. What fails is using `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` or `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP`, hence for instance `\delimsize` is not available.

Comment: @Blaisorblade: As this is a rather old post, I don't remember the details, but I suppose it didn't work when I tested it. Maybe there was a problem with the 2014 version of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`? As it worked with the optional argument (which is preferable in my opinion), I didn't investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution similar to [LaRiFaRi's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32245/larifari) but with a different alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}    
\begin{split}
  R = \{&(S_{1},S_{1}), (S_{1},S_{4}), (S_{4},S_{4}), (S_{4},S_{1}), (S_{2},S_{2}), (S_{2},S_{3}),\\
        &(S_{3},S_{3}), (S_{3},S_{2}), (S_{0},S_{0}), (S_{0},S_{5}), (S_{5},S_{5}), (S_{5},S_{0})\}
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice the horizontal alignment of the elements.